# Reference for Classical probability theory implemented on General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, probability, adm-formalism

I am looking for a reference for something like : a probability density put on the [ADM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism) phase space, thereby making the metric probabilistic in the classical probability sense. **But not exactly this**. I need this for a general spacetime,  i.e. without the assumption of ADM that you can foliate spacetime into space-like slices. The Hamiltonian formulation will go away if you throw away this assumption.

So I need **probability densities implemented on GR in a covariant way**, i.e. time should be treated equally as space. Things like time loops should be allowed in principle. The formulation should be agnostic to the nature of time.

Comment: Why do you want time loops ? Initial value problem will not be well posed if such a thing exists

Comment: @KP99 I don't explicitly want a formulation for time loops. I want the formulation to be agnostic to them,  just like it's agonostic to the topology to space.

Comment: @KP99 I also think the quantum version will be unable to avoid time loops because the metric will have to be path integrated over all possibilities.